# Get current configuration in OnConfiguring method EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, command-line-interface

I have a class library project with db context, models and migrations and I want to create a full migration script using the following command:

```
dotnet ef migrations script --output C:/SQL/tododbscript.sql --idempotent --project C:/Work/repos/Example/src/Example.DB/Example.DB.csproj --configuration UAT
```

And the main problem is to get `--configuration` in `OnConfiguring` method of my db context. I tried the following solution but `envName` is `null` here:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
            if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                return;
            }
            var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

            Console.WriteLine(envName);
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
              .Build();


            Console.WriteLine(configuration.GetConnectionString("ExampleDb"));

            _ = optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("ExampleDb"));
 }
```

Maybe someone knows how to extract current configuration here?

Comment: Use `AddDbContext` in your application's startup or Program.cs instead. Right now you're overriding anything passed from the command line. And far worse, re-reading only parts of the application configuration.

Comment: I have neither Program.cs nor application's startup as I'm using dll as migration project

Comment: The project that uses your DLL does though. That's where DI and configuration are meant to be set up. *Your* DLL shouldn't care where its settings come from at all

Comment: The migrations docs explicitly cover [putting the DbContext and migrations in different projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: I have only DLL project without any Web API or console projects

Comment: Then you don't have any settings and can't execute anything at all. You can't run any code on any operating system without an executable process. Wherever  you want to use your DLL, there will be a process that will load it and start it. Even if, eg you're creating a native Win32 API wrapper, it's still a bad idea to hard-code your configuration inside your data class.

Comment: Besides, any command-line options you specify will be passed to the DbContext class as `DbContextOptions` values. What you do will override anything you passed from the command line

Comment: But when I'm running the command I've provided above, it's starts the migration process and calls OnConfiguring method. Probably EF executable process triggers it but I can't receive --configuration option I passed in command

Comment: Besides, settings aren't loaded from `appsettings` files only. Nor is `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` the only variable used to detect a development or production environment. The default configuration settings use JSON files, environment variables *and* command line parameters. What you try to do may end up connecting to the wrong database if at all

Comment: So, don't you know how to extract value provided in --configuration option in the code this way?

Comment: With [#if DEBUG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation). The [--configuration switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options) is `The build configuration, for example: Debug or Release.`. You don't read it at runtime. If you really want to modify your code based on the build configuration, you'll have to set compilation flags and test them.